# Sending Integer from JSP to Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

Unable to send an Integer from Servlet to JSP.

```java
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Method Get in MyServlet");
        int Gconta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Gcont"));
        Gconta = Gconta + 1;
        System.out.println(Gconta);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("NGconta", Gconta);
        response.sendRedirect("cabecalhost.jsp");

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

The JSP page

```
<body>  
    <h3>O Resultado NGconta:</h3> 

    <%String Getnumbx = request.getParameter("NGconta"); %>
    <%= Getnumbx %>

    <%String Getnumb = (String) request.getAttribute("NGconta");%>
    <% out.println("Your Result is "+ Getnumb);  %>

    &{NGconta}; 

</body>
```

Comment: It gives a "null" answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Method Get in MyServlet");
        int Gconta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Gcont"));
        Gconta = Gconta + 1;
        System.out.println(Gconta);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("NGconta", Gconta);
        RequestDispatcher rd = 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("cabecalhost.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}


<body>  
    <%String Getnumbx = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("NGconta"); %>
    <%= Getnumbx %>
</body>
```

Comment: It says type mismatch cannot convert from object to string

Comment: getAttribute returns an object  you need to cast it, i edit my response, please check now